# Cling with tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat7, cling

I am trying to create a service to autodiscover upnp devices in my local network, implementing it in a webapplication running on tomcat 7 and using 4thline Cling library.
I got this error

> org.fourthline.cling.transport.RouterImpl handleStartFailure
>   SEVERE: Unable to initialize network router: org.fourthline.cling.transport.spi.InitializationException: Failed to set modified URLStreamHandlerFactory in this environment. Can't use bundled default client based on HTTPURLConnection, see manual.

In the [cling's manual](http://4thline.org/projects/cling/faq.html#t3) they say that Cling couldn't use the Java JDK's HTTPURLConnection for HTTP client operations. They suggest to [configure network transport](http://4thline.org/projects/cling/core/manual/cling-core-manual.html#section.ConfiguringTransports).

I didn't understand well how to do. Anyone had a similar problem?
Can you suggest me an example?

Thanks.

The code I am using is:

```
    public class Example {

    public static void startDiscovery() {

        RegistryListener listener = new RegistryListener() {

            public void remoteDeviceDiscoveryStarted(Registry registry,RemoteDevice device) {


                    String name = device.getDisplayString();
                    String url = device.getDetails().getBaseURL().toString();
                    String friendlyName = device.getDetails().getFriendlyName();


            }

            public void remoteDeviceDiscoveryFailed(Registry registry,RemoteDevice device, Exception ex) {
            }

            public void remoteDeviceAdded(Registry registry, RemoteDevice device) {
            }

            public void remoteDeviceUpdated(Registry registry,RemoteDevice device) {
            }

            public void remoteDeviceRemoved(Registry registry,RemoteDevice device) {
            }

            public void localDeviceAdded(Registry registry, LocalDevice device) {
            }

            public void localDeviceRemoved(Registry registry, LocalDevice device) {
            }

            public void beforeShutdown(Registry registry) {
            }

            public void afterShutdown() {
            }
        };


        try{

            UpnpService upnpService = new UpnpServiceImpl(listener);
            upnpService.getControlPoint().search(new STAllHeader());
            // wait 5 seconds for them to respond
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            upnpService.shutdown();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```